# Cordova: IOS / Android - push notifications token detector / regex pattern

Tags: android, ios, regex, cordova, push-notification

Is there any way to detect weather the token received by the user is an android or ios token?

When I get the token I know if it's android/ios and I can save it for later and send the pushes.

But I want to save just the tokens and then use some **regex pattern** to detect if it's an android or ios token.

any help?

Comment: To come up with a regex, you should know the pattern, and it must meet the requirements of a regular language. Note that iOS and java/android regex flavors do not support recursion. What have you tried?

Comment: What do the tokens look like? Is there some attribute that differs between them?

Comment: iOS tokens are shorter and they are between "<" and ">" chars, but the plugin you use will probably remove those characters.

Answer (score 0):

I just had a look at the ~3000 or so device tokens I've got stored in my database for my iOS / Android app, and based on this, it looks like:

Apple uses the following character set: `[0-9a-f]`
Android (GCM) uses the following character set: `[0-9A-Za-z\_:-]`
 
(I'm not sure about FCM because I haven't migrated yet, but apparently the tokens are similar to GCM)

However, because neither Apple nor Google specify what character sets are used, one should assume that they'll change at any moment and avoid using things like regex to determine platform.